# matlab r2022b license checkout failed in ubuntu

Tags: matlab

I tried to find the solution. but nothing helped me...
Here is the error I get after setting "activate_matlab.sh"
when I try to start the Matlab by using "matlab" command , this error comes...

`MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -9
Your username does not match the username in the license file.
To run on this computer, you must run the Activation client to reactivate your license.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting:
https://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2022b/9

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: MATLAB
License path: /home/########/.matlab/R2022b_licenses:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2022b/licenses/license.dat:/usr/local/MA
TLAB/R2022b/licenses/trial_11####11_R2022b.lic
Licensing error: -9,57.
`

I tried to find solutions in opensource channels like youTube and SOF. No solution worked. Some people said to buy me license, some said to try offline. some said matlab already running.

but things didn't work with me.

Comment: Did you go to the link which the error told you to visit? Did you contact MathWorks support to tell them the license you're paying for isn't being detected?

Comment: yes, i do. but didn't understood what they tried to say.

Comment: It sounds like you should reply to them asking for further clarification of anything you found unclear - they will have the deepest insight and most experience handling something related to licensing, it's part of MathWorks support's job to resolve those issues

Comment: @Wolfie Thank you. I talked to them. It works fine and they were really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your username does not match the username in the license file.

Check your username. It should be your "PC Username".

You will find it in "Settings > About > Device Name"

And also using licensed product is always preferable.